# Unable to authenticate when accessing Cloudant using Api Key via pouchDB

Tags: pouchdb, cloudant

first off, im brand new to using cloudant, so this has been a very steep learning curve for me. any help is appreciated. All the information ive been able to find thus far has been from seemingly out of date SO posts from a few years ago.

I have set up a service which is showing up correctly in my resource list:
[image]

If I click on that service, I can see the service credentials are made correctly for it (info redacted):

```
{
  "apikey": "********************************************",
  "host": "******************-bluemix.cloudantnosqldb.appdomain.cloud",
  "url": "https://***********-bluemix.cloudantnosqldb.appdomain.cloud",
  "username": "***********-bluemix"
}
```

But, when I try to access this with these credentials in pouchDB with the following code:

```
let db = new PouchDB(userCredentials.url,  {
        auth: {
            username: 'userCredentials.username',
            password: 'userCredentials.apiKey'
        }
    });
```

I am met with an error that it was unable to authenticate with bad username or password.

Ive also tried going through the IAM management section and using the service credentials there, making sure that my credentials have API keys attached. when using that method, I set my auth object to username: apikeyname, and password: actual key value. but every time, i am still getting the same authentication error.

Any insights anyone has would be a huge help! A few notes, I have made sure CORS is enabled, and I have the authentication setting set to IAM only (legacy login is disabled)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have requested an IAM-only authentication account, you can't use basic auth. Unfortunately, there's no support for IAM in PouchDB at the time of writing.

Comment: oh my god thank you, that would have saved me so much time. so I just need to allow legacy login and then follow the same process, but look for a password somewhere?

Comment: If you have legacy auth, you can then create api keys to let PouchDB use. Don't use the root account credentials, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Will the auth object I pass to pouchDB look the same as I have above? the legacy api keys just have passwords on them?

Answer (score 1):

The password you are looking for is `password` instead of `apikey`.

You can either use regular / basic auth with username and password or use IAM API keys, but you can't mix them.

Comment: Ok, so first off, I guess I need to allow legacy auth again. Once I do that, will this password start showing up somewhere? Currently Im never given a password anywhere when trying to set up these credentials

Comment: Just tap the button to open the Cloudant dashboard. Then go to the permissions bit for your database and create an api key